# Selecting A folder Python

Tags: python, directory

I'm new to python and want to code for specific characteristics in folders and then perform operations on the contents within the desired folder. This is an example below:

```
Path = "./Desktop/Example/"          #Input Directory
A_files = []                                                                    
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                            
    for filename in fileList:                                                       
        if "[A]" in subdirList()
        if ".txt" in filename.lower():                                                  
            A_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename)) 

#Perform Mathematical Operators for A_files only

B_files = []                                                                    
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                            
    for filename in fileList:                                                       
        if "[B]" in subdirList()
        if ".txt" in filename.lower():                                                  
            B_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))

 #Perform Mathematical Operators for B_files only

 #Perform Mathematical Operators between A_files and B_files together
```

In folder "Example" are sub folders: Hello_World[A] and Hello_World[B] and I want to access all .txt files in each folder individually at first to perform a scaling of the values. Later I do other mathematical operators between the two files.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I select a folder based on only a part of the name? Like in the last if statement I am able to select only .txt files I only want to choose the folder that contain [A] in it

Comment: I think the `glob` module can do wildcard-style partial matching. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: The thing is I know over time the prefix is going to change but i know the [A] convention and the [B] convention will remain the same. I need to find a way to isolate Hello_World[A] and Hi_World[B] through the directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for something like this:

```
Path = "./Desktop/Example/"          #Input Directory
A_files = []                                                                    
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                            
    for filename in fileList:                                                       
        if "[A]" in dirName:
            if ".txt" in filename.lower():                                                  
                A_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename)) 

#Perform Mathematical Operators for A_files only

B_files = []                                                                    
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                            
    for filename in fileList:                                                       
        if "[B]" in dirName:
            if ".txt" in filename.lower():                                                  
                B_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))

 #Perform Mathematical Operators for B_files only
 for f in B:
     data = open(filename).read()
     # Do stuff

 #Perform Mathematical Operators between A_files and B_files together
 for index, file in enumerate(A):
     dataA = open(A[i]).read()
     dataB = open(B[i]).read()
     # Do something
```

Since `dirname` is a string, you can use `in` to check its contents.

Then, you can iterate over your `A[]` and `B[]` to do your math, and use enumerate to iterate over both using an index.  See here: [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)